# How to use a generic vector in c++

Tags: c++, vector, types

I need a vector that can store int's or float's or string's or char's or any other primitive data type inside itself.

How can I declare such a datatype ?

For example, if I use `std::vector<int> vIntVector;` vIntVector is only capable of storing integers, not std::string's or floats.

P.S. I do not have C++11 support

Comment: You want Boost.Variant or Boost.Any.

Comment: This is a weird question. Can you make a simpler version of it? Like, "I want a variable `x` that can be of any type.", with usage examples? Surely we don't need to know whether you stick things into vectors or pairs.

Comment: @KerrekSB I have edited the question. Thanks for the suggestion. Also, if the requirement seems a little unorthodox, let me mention that I am writing a decoder and the messages (the protocol) are a little vague at times. I am unsure of what the datatype of an array that they will be sending is going to be. Thus, I need to be ready with support for all primitive types.

Comment: can someone please explain why this question has a close vote ?

Comment: @Wildling: This question is still wildly unclear. Cut all the irrelevant stuff about vectors and pairs (we trust you to know what those are), and make a stripped down, *minimal* presentation of the core problem you need to solve. Make it so that a solution of the core problem allows you to solve your real problem, without telling us about pairs.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use `Boost.Variant` if you know the *possible* types already. Else use `Boost.Any`.

If you cannot use Boost, may be because it is too huge, then still use it!

If you still don't want to use it, see their implementation, *learn from them* and then define your own classes.

Comment: *If you cannot use Boost, because it it too huge, then still use it.* made me chuckle.

Answer (score 1):

Well, as I understood, u just want an array to store variable of different types. Unfortunately there is no simple way to do it in C++. I can suggest you the following solution.

```
struct Var{
   enum {INT, FLOAT, BYTE} type;
   union{
      int integer;
      float decimal;
      unsigned char byte;
   };
   Var(int v):type(INT), integer(v){}
   Var(float v):type(FLOAT), decimal(v){}
   Var(unsigned char v):type(BYTE), byte(v){}
};

...
std::vector<Var> arr;
arr.push_back(1); // Push integer
arr.push_back(12.f); // Push float
arr.push_back('a'); // Push char(byte)
```

But I'd recommend you to not use this. Try to think about other way to implement what you need.